# python returns error when using bbox with pyscreenshot

Tags: python, python-3.x, screenshot

my code

```
im = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(on_click.px, on_click.py, on_click.rx, on_click.ry))
im.save('img.png')
```

returned error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cww\Downloads\Typeracer Bot\typeracerbot.py", line 21, in <module>
    im = pyscreenshot.grab(bbox=(on_click.px, on_click.py, on_click.rx, on_click.ry))
  File "C:\Users\cww\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreenshot\__init__.py", line 27, in grab
    raise ValueError("bbox x2<=x1")
ValueError: bbox x2<=x1
```

**im trying to save an image of the whole screen with a click of the mouse and then print that text where i put the mouse (the img printed gets saved in the folder)**

Comment: Check the values of on_click.px, on_click.py, on_click.rx, on_click.ry. Looks like the second x value is lower than the first